# Text animation help

Tags: animation, text-object, force-fields

I have created a text with a metallic material and converted each letter to a mesh and applied rigid body physics.
Now, I want to make an animation where a plane (or maybe a magnet) flies over the text and magnetizes the letters and takes them away (and then maybe drops them somewhere else). I tried a few force fields, but didn't have any luck because I don't know much about them.

Comment: You could make a particle emitter that emits just enough particles for each letter. Then add the individual letters as an object group, you can choose the order of display. These will be affected by the force fields.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I have to animate that. And it looks fine. Force fields are for particles.